# Update new column with value from jSON in the same row Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I had a table with 20k products. In this table I had a jSON column which contained several information about the product. I had to add a new column by a requirement of my boss which will contain the model name (which is inside the jSON).
How can I do it?
My table product has id = id of the product
product_description = jSON with many details about the product
and now a new column model_name which my boss wants available outside the jSON

I usually did this query:

```
SELECT "productInfo"->'product_info'->>'model_name' AS model_name FROM inv.product WHERE id = 1
```

to obtain the model_name

I want to update all the products so the model_name is now in the new column model_name but i couldn't do it because i'm not familiar with mass updates.

What i want to do in words is:

```
UPDATE inv.product SET model_name = ( QUERY TO SELECT THE VALUE OF THE model_name ) FOR EACH ROW
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
UPDATE inv.product
SET model_name = "productInfo"->'product_info'->>'model_name'
WHERE id = 1;
```

Or

```
UPDATE inv.product
SET model_name = "productInfo"->'product_info'->>'model_name';
```

If you want to update all records in `inv.product`.

Comment: Thanks, that's the right answer, in both cases, i figured it out a few minutes ago, and didn't realize that the answer was so simple!